# A two-user tic tac toe using JSF

Tags: java, jsp, jsf

I'm trying to write a two-user tic tac toe using JSF technology.
From the books and tutorials I've read I understand how JSF's work and how to write a web-app for one user to use, say a Celsius to Fahrenheit converter or something like that.

What I can't find anywhere is how to implement the app in such a way that two users (on different computers) can actually be connected to each other and play a tic-tac-toe game with one another. So I guess I somehow have to grant acces to a particular Bean for those two users, authenticated via login, but then, the Bean itself would have to know which user is taking action, so the game can have turns.

Is there any known way how to implement something like that? Could anyone point me a tutorial or something on this topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for ajax push. The standard JSF component library does not support it out the box because the implementation is as of now servletcontainer dependent and JSF is designed to be servletcontainer independent. The future Servlet 3.1 specification (part of Java EE 7) will introduce websockets support which thus allows for standardized push possibilities. The future JSF 3.0 will likely support it.

As of now, among others the [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org) JSF component library has [a `<p:push>` component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/index.jsf) (click the link to see live examples) which uses the [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) servletcontainer under the covers. Installation details of `<p:push>` are outlined in chapter 6 of PrimeFaces [User's Guide](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html).

Just play around with the examples provided on PrimeFaces site and you'll get the picture how to implement it for your tic tac toe idea.