# Primefaces JSF null returned from RequestContext.getCurrentInstance()

Tags: jsf, primefaces, nullpointerexception, requestcontext

I'm developing an app using Primefaces tag library.

So far I've copied some examples from their official website and all seems to work except for anything that uses the RequestContext.getCurrentInstance() method. It either returns null every time, causing Tomcat to throw a NullPointer exception or hangs forever, never returning anything.

Here's my code (the case where it hangs):

GlobalCounterBean.java

```
package org.primefaces.examples.view;

import java.io.Serializable;
import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;

public class GlobalCounterBean implements Serializable{

    private int count;

    public int getCount() {
    return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
    this.count = count;
    }

    public synchronized void increment() {
    count++;
    System.out.println("aaaa");
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().push("counter", count);
    }
}
```

test.xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
    </h:head>   
    <h:body>    

        <p:spinner />   

        <h:form>
    <h:outputText value="#{globalCounter.count}" styleClass="ui-widget display" />

    <br />

    <p:commandButton value="Click" actionListener="#{globalCounter.increment}" />
</h:form>

<p:push onmessage="handleMessage" channel="counter" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleMessage(evt, data) {
            $('.display').html(data);
    }
</script>


    </h:body>
</html>
```

And here's the code for the case when it returns null (all files are in the same project):

ChatController.java:

```
    package org.primefaces.examples.view;

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Set;

    import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
    import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
    import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

    import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;


    public class ChatController implements Serializable {

        private final static String CHANNEL = "chat";

        private String message;

        private String username;

        private boolean loggedIn;

        private Set<String> users = new HashSet<String>();

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }
        public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }
        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public boolean isLoggedIn() {
            return loggedIn;
        }
        public void setLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn) {
            this.loggedIn = loggedIn;
        }

        public void send() {
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().push(CHANNEL, username + ": "+  message);

            message = null;
        }

        public void login() {

            RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();

            if(users.contains(username)) {
                loggedIn = false;
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Username taken", "Try with another username."));

                requestContext.addPartialUpdateTarget("growl");
            }
            else {
                users.add(username);
                loggedIn = true;

                requestContext.push(CHANNEL, username + " joined the channel.");
            }
        }

        public void disconnect() {
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().push(CHANNEL, username + " has left the channel.");
            loggedIn = false;
            username = null;
        }
    }
```

chat.xhtml

```
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
        <title>Insert title here</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <f:view>
        <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />

        <h:form>

            <p:fieldset id="container" legend="PrimeChat">

                <h:panelGroup rendered="#{chatController.loggedIn}" >
                    <p:outputPanel layout="block" style="width:600px;height:200px;overflow:auto" 
                               styleClass="chatroom" />
                    <p:spinner />
                    <p:separator />

                    <p:inputText value="#{chatController.message}" styleClass="messageInput" />
                    <p:spacer width="5" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Send" actionListener="#{chatController.send}" global="false" oncomplete="$('.messageInput').val('').focus()"/>
                    <p:spacer width="5" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Disconnect" actionListener="#{chatController.disconnect}" global="false" 
                                        oncomplete="chatAgent.close()" update="container" />
                </h:panelGroup>

                <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not chatController.loggedIn}" >
                    Username: <p:inputText value="#{chatController.username}" />

                    <p:spacer width="5" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Login" actionListener="#{chatController.login}" update="container" 
                                     icon="ui-icon-person"/>
                </h:panelGroup>

            </p:fieldset>

        </h:form>

        <p:push onmessage="handleMessage" channel="chat" widgetVar="chatAgent" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function handleMessage(evt, data) {
                var chatContent = $('.chatContent');
                chatContent.append(data + '<br />');

                //keep scroll
                chatContent.scrollTop(chatContent.height());
            }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function handleComplete(xhr, status, args) {
            if(args.validationFailed) {
                PrimeFaces.debug("Validation Failed");
            } 
            else {
                PrimeFaces.debug("Save:" + args.saved);
                PrimeFaces.debug("FirstName: " + args.user.firstname + ", Lastname: " + args.user.lastname); 
            }
        }
        </script>

        </f:view>
        </body>
        </html>
```

faces-config.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <faces-config version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">
     <managed-bean eager="true">
      <managed-bean-name>chatController</managed-bean-name>
      <managed-bean-class>org.primefaces.examples.view.ChatController</managed-bean-class>
      <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
     </managed-bean>
     <managed-bean>
      <managed-bean-name>globalCounter</managed-bean-name>
      <managed-bean-class>org.primefaces.examples.view.GlobalCounterBean</managed-bean-class>
      <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
     </managed-bean>
     <!--
        No ManagedBean declarations here as we are using @ManagedBean Annotations.
        -->
    </faces-config>
```

web.xml:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <web-app version="2.5"
            xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" >

            <welcome-file-list>
                <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
            </welcome-file-list>

            <servlet>
                <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
                <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
            </servlet>

            <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
            </servlet-mapping>

        </web-app>
```

And here's the exception thrown in tomcat console:

```
                        2012-05-27 19:16:25 com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl log
            SEVERE: JSF1073: javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException caught during processing of INVOKE_APPLICATION 5 : UIComponent-ClientId=j_idt2:j_idt16, Message=java.lang.NullPointerException
            2012-05-27 19:16:25 com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl log
            SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
            javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:178)
                at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:84)
                at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:773)
                at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:296)
                at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:781)
                at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1246)
                at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:77)
                at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
                at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
                at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at org.primefaces.examples.view.ChatController.login(ChatController.java:69)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
                at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:191)
                at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
                at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
                ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `web.xml` is missing the "URL Configuration" part of PrimeFaces Push setup.

As mentioned in my answer on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758147/a-two-user-tic-tac-toe-using-jsf), Installation details of PrimeFaces Push are outlined in chapter 6 of PrimeFaces [User's Guide](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html). Here's an extract of relevance for the step you're missing:

> ## 6.1 Setup
>
> #### Push Server
>
> PrimeFaces Push uses a servlet as a dispatcher. This servlet should be in a different application than the JSF application and at the moment can only be deployed on jetty server.
>
> ```xml
> <servlet>
>     <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
>     <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
>     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
>     <init-param>
>         <param-name>channels</param-name>
>         <param-value>chat,counter</param-value>
>     </init-param>
> </servlet>
> <servlet-mapping>
>     <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
>     <url-pattern>/prime-push/*</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
> ```
>
> channels configuration defines the topic names that push server can publish to.
>
> #### URL Configuration
>
> The JSF application needs to define the push server url to send messages.
>
> ```xml
> <context-param>
>     <param-name>primefaces.PUSH_SERVER_URL</param-name>
>     <param-value>ws://url_to_push_server</param-value>
> </context-param>
> ```

Comment: It seems though that it can only be deployed on Jetty server, which pretty much makes the whole solution useless for me since I have to run it on Tomcat. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Perhaps you didn't understand that you're supposed to run them next each other? Jetty is solely supposed to handle push, you can just keep Tomcat running for your webapp. Because, as explained in my answer on your previous question, there is no single standard to handle push, PrimeFaces has just choosen Jetty as reference server for push, otherwise it'd be a total waste of time to write push logic for every single server which exist nowadays (Tomcat, Jetty, Glassfish, Weblogic, Websphere, JBoss, etc..etc..). Jetty was chosen because it's so small and has good native websockets support.

Comment: So, if I understand it correctly, I should create a new Eclipse project just for the Servlet, modify only its web.xml and then run it on Jetty? And then, in my old application in web.xml add the primefaces.PUSH_SERVER_URL declaration? I'll try that in a moment, but first I have to install Jetty.

Comment: Ok, so I've installed Jetty and it runs on localhost:8989 while Tomcat runs on localhost:8080. I'm still not sure how to deploy the org.primefaces.push.PushServlet. Since Jetty, for reasons unknown to me, won't run from Eclipse, I run it from terminal and I tried to deploy the app manually. In Jetty_home_dir/webapps I have a catalog with the web app in which in WEB-INF/lib I've put the primefaces-3.3.RC1.jar file and in my web.xml I've pasted the xml code you gave me.

Comment: Ive also added this code: "<param-name>primefaces.PUSH_SERVER_URL</param-name><param-value>http://localhost:8989/</param-value>" to my old app web.xml file. So far, it doesn't work. Frankly, it's the first time I try to use webapps, so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong and it's probably with the app I have to deploy on Jetty. Should this app have something more than the primefaces jar and updated web.xml to work?