# FacesContext.getCurrentInstance returns null in PrimeFaces Dialog Framework demo

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, nullpointerexception, facescontext

I want to run the ShowCase demo of [Dialog Framework - Data](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/df/data.xhtml) on GlassFish 4.1 and NetBeans 8.0.2. I Copy/Paste code from showcase. But I encountered a NullPointerException on this line:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
```

Error Code

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Beans.DFView.onCarChosen(CalculateBean.java:27)
```

I read that I must have another servlet application to client communication , but i can't find any link with tutorial how to do it.

I read that I must add this code to faces-config.xml:

```
<application>
    <action-listener>org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener</action-listener>
    <navigation-handler>org.primefaces.application.DialogNavigationHandler</navigation-handler>
    <view-handler>org.primefaces.application.DialogViewHandler</view-handler>
</application>
```

Link to Natalia Zoń post : [Primefaces JSF null returned from RequestContext.getCurrentInstance()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775906/primefaces-jsf-null-returned-from-requestcontext-getcurrentinstance)
Here i read someting about Push Server : [Developer.am](http://www.developer.am/primefaces/?page=Setup)

Answer (score 0):

Ok for first , my mistake was that my code was dirty , because i tried so many solutions , developing web applications you must be 2x more clean than making something on desktop applications , because this type of applications is more sensitive.

Also , after i read http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html#AccessingTheFacesContextInsideHttpServletOrFilter , i'm going to learn the servlet technology and try to make it.

PS: The solution was simple , clean your code , add this to your faces-config:

```
<application>
    <action-listener>
        org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener
    </action-listener>
    <navigation-handler>
        org.primefaces.application.DialogNavigationHandler
    </navigation-handler>
    <view-handler>
        org.primefaces.application.DialogViewHandler
    </view-handler>
</application>
```

and it must run.
If not , make new WebApplication project , and copy/paste all code from showcase and it must run if not , replay.